# How to Create a Contact layout with Image on Left Side and Text View on Right

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to create a layout for my app with Contact Details of Tuition Centers in Scroll view that includes "About Section" on Right Side and Image on Left. But Image overlaps  Texts on Textview and I couldn't figure out on how to solve it. Here is the Sample  image I want layout to have

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your xml code please

Comment: also the image is on right side and the textviews are on left side

Comment: @Androidteem I don't have xml..I found some random code on internet and tried but it didn't work out...I'm very new to android development..I am just getting infomation on linearlayout, constraintlayout , Relativelayout...!! So sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which type of layout you use, but for such complex layouts I reccomend to use ConstraintLayout, with it layout will be as following:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Activity1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_school_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5588AA"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Nimble International Academy"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        android:tint="#33AA33"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_school_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_deals_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_school_name"
        tools:text="Deals in: "/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_deals_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_deals_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_deals_title"
        tools:text="training languages, bsc tuition class, msc entrance"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_school_photo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/academy"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_deals_text"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_about_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv_school_photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_school_photo"
        tools:text="About"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv_school_photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_about_title"
        tools:text="01-424154"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_phone1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv_school_photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_phone"
        tools:text="01-424154"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_phone2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv_school_photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_phone1"
        tools:text="01-424154"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```